How can I apply the acrylic effect to a button for vb.net?
I would like to add an acrylic effect to a button on my form that already has code, but I can't find the way yet.
I would like to achieve something like the following image
I even searched for nuget libraries but I still couldn't apply such an effect to a button. I am very new to programming...
